# Resolver errors when trying to import a jar in Android Studio

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, libraries, resolver

I'm been trying to add a jar in my Android Studio project.

I already edited my build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile files('/libs/capptain-sdk-android-2.2.0/capptain.jar')
}
```

The code works fine (it compile and I have what I want in my app) but when I look at my code I have a lot of errors from the resolver :

[image]

I think that I might have forgotten something somewhere to tell him that com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.activity.CapptainActivity exist. Any ideas ?

**Edit:**
Here are all my build files, the main one :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    version = '1.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

And the one specific for my module :

```
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile group:'com.google.code.gson', name:'gson', version:'2.2.4'
    compile project(':libs:volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('/libs/capptain-sdk-android-2.2.0/capptain.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you sync your project with Gradle after modifying the build files by hand?

Comment: Yes I did multiple times without any change :/

Comment: Let's see all your build files.

Comment: I added them to my question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I didn't notice it before, but the fact that you have '/libs/capptain-sdk-android-2.2.0/capptain.jar' as a dependency is suspicious -- that leading slash makes it a filesystem absolute path, and you should delete it. I don't know if that will fix your problem, though, if it still compiles. Other than that, though I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: It doesn't change anything (in fact, on windows I have to set a complete path while on ios I have to write it like that). Thanks anyway for your help.